# Is it possible to pass difference service instances to the children components similar to React Context

Tags: angular

For example a have this service

```
class Service {
  constructor(public name:string){}
}
```

And I want to pass different instances of it to the children components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <div>{{service.name}}</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(public service: Service){}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(public service: Service){}
}
```

In React it could be done by using context. Something like this

```
const ServiceContext = React.createContext<Service>({} as any);

function ChildComponent(){
    const service = useContext(ServiceContext)

    return <div>{service.name}</div>
}
export function ContextTest(){

    const service1 = new Service("foo")
    const service2 = new Service("bar")

    return <div>
        <ServiceContext.Provider value={service1}>
            <ChildComponent/>
        </ServiceContext.Provider>
        <ServiceContext.Provider value={service2}>
            <ChildComponent/>
        </ServiceContext.Provider>
    </div>

}
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Angular?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done. The trick is to declare the service in the `providers` array of the components who will use it, but not in the `Module`.

When you 'provide' a service at the `Module` level, a single instance becomes available for DI to every component within that `Module`.

But if you 'provide' it at the component level, that component gets a brand new instance of the service each time.

Take a look at the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services) here for more info.

A basic example using one of your components' `@Component` decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<div>{{service.name}}</div>`,
  providers:  [Service]
})
```

Do this for each component that will want it's own instance and, once again, make sure you don't put the service in the `Module's` `providers` array.

Edit:

If you want the parent component to be aware of the services (and their values), then it could just create them manually and pass them in via `@Input()` bindings.

To give a quick example, your components would have a property like this:

`@Input() service: Service;`

Then in your parent's HTML:

```
<child-component [service]="new Service('foo')"></child-component>
<child-component [service]="new Service('bar')"></child-component>
```

Alternatively, create fields on the parent like:

```
fooService = new Service('foo');
barService = new Service('bar');
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<child-component [service]="fooService"></child-component>
<child-component [service]="barService"></child-component>
```

Edit 2:

While I do not believe this can be achieved using Angular's DI out of the box, I think there may be a way to achieve the desired result (and still use constructor DI).

To start, create a 'config' type, something like:

```
export interface ServiceConfig {
    name: string;
}
```

Now, modify your service like so:

```
export class Service {
    private config: ServiceConfig;

    constructor() {
    }

    registerConfig(config: ServiceConfig) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this.config.name;
    }
}
```

And then in your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<div>{{service.name}}</div>`,
  providers: [Service]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() serviceConfig: ServiceConfig;

   constructor(private service: Service) {
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.service.registerConfig(this.serviceConfig);
   }
}
```

The last thing then is to hook up the unique configs to each child component in the parent template:

```
<child-component [serviceConfig]="{ name: 'fooService' }"></child-component>
<child-component [serviceConfig]="{ name: 'barService' }"></child-component>
```

This is not exactly an elegant solution, but it satisfies your (what I consider to be very strange) requirements.

Comment: But I need to set "foo" and "bar" in the parent component.

Comment: I would like to use DI instead of @Input() because in this case it would be available in any component below the child component tree, similar to React example

Comment: Please see my second edit.  Not the best solution, but it might sort your issue.